# Maintain input data in Activity A when start Activity B, then return to Activity A with data from Activity B

Tags: java, android

I have Actviity A, for when the user has to input their Post title, description, category, type and location.

In activity A, the user enters their data. Then to select location on a Map, Activity B opens up. The user selects a location in Activity B. The app must then bring the location data from Activity B to Activity A.

So basically, I need to *maintain the data entered in Activity A while entering Activity B* and **return data from Activity B to activity A.**

I have used the Override `OnSaveInstanceState` and `OnRestoreInstanceState` to **successfully** maintain the data in Activity A.

The problem is, when I try to open Activity A through Activity B and pass the data.

The code in Activity B for opening Activity A is as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);

            i.putExtra("name", placeName);
            i.putExtra("address", placeAddress);
            i.putExtra("lat", latitude);
            i.putExtra("lng", longitude);
            startActivity(i);
```

But this, **clears** the data saved in Activity A and passes in Activity B data.

How to pass data and start Activity A without clearing emptying the data saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I understands is theres no need to send data from Activity A to Activity B because Activity B doesn't have any concerns with data from previous activity. Just start Activity B using `ActivityResultLauncher` then putextra any params and then get that param in activity A. Simple example is below.

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent data = result.getData();
            // get extra's from intent which was passed from activity B
        }
    });
```

Launch as below

```
launcher.launch(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
```

Sending required param from Activity B

```
Intent i= new Intent();
i.putExtra("lat", latitude);
i.putExtra("lng", longitude);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Comment: Let me know if there's anything which is missed while understanding the problem